# Master/Detail flow with a FragmentPagerAdapter in DetailsFragment

Tags: java, android, master-detail, fragmentpageradapter

I have implemented the Master/Detail flow in my Android project. I have an Activity called "StatisticsActivity" whose layout has 2 fragments, the PlayerStatsFragment (as master) and the GameStatsFragment (as detail). So far all good, the problem is that I want inside the GameStatsFragment to be 2 Tabs (Fragment301 and Fragment302), so when I choose an item from PlayersFragment to send an id(playerId) and show diferent content in GamesFragments.

I hope the image helps to understand:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZBVp.png

I followed this 3 part tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fl0xMuo10yA and I have implemented a FragmentPagerAdapter to create the tabs(and FragmentA, FragmentB). The problem is that in the GamesFragment I receive the playersId but in the MyPagersAdapter the players id is always null and crashes.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Below is my code. Thanks a lot!

** UPDATE ** 
If I initialize the playerId then the app doesn't crash, but when click on an item then everything disapears.

**The DetailFragment**

```
public class GameStatsFragment extends Fragment {

@Bind(R.id.pager)
ViewPager mPager;
@Bind(R.id.tabs)
SlidingTabLayout mTabs;
MyPagerAdapter adapter;
public String playerId;

public GameStatsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game_stats, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    if (arguments != null) {
        playerId = arguments.getString("player_id");
        Log.i("GAME_STATS_FRAGMENT", playerId);
    }

    adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(this.getChildFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}

class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment301 fragment301 = Fragment301.getInstance(position, playerId);
        return fragment301;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

}

**The Fragment301**

```
public class Fragment301 extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

@Bind(R.id.games_played_textview)
TextView gamesPlayedTextView;
@Bind(R.id.games_won_textview)
TextView gamesWonTextView;
@Bind(R.id.darts_thrown_textview)
TextView dartsThrownTextView;
@Bind(R.id.darts_missed_textview)
TextView dartsMissedTextView;
@Bind(R.id.total_score_textview)
TextView totalScoreTextView;
@Bind(R.id.three_darts_average_textview)
TextView threeDartsAverageTextView;
private String playerId;

public static Fragment301 getInstance(int position, String playerId) {
    Fragment301 mFragment = new Fragment301();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("position", position);
    args.putString("player_id", playerId);
    mFragment.setArguments(args);
    Log.i("FRAGMENT301", "position: " + position + "playerid: " + playerId );
    return mFragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment301, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);



    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    if (arguments != null) {
        playerId = arguments.getString("player_id");
    }



    getActivity().getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Log.i("FRAGMENT301", ""+playerId);
    return new CursorLoader(
            getActivity(),
            PlayersContract.GameEntry.CONTENT_URI,
             null,
            PlayersContract.GameEntry._ID + " = ? AND " + PlayersContract.GameEntry.COLUMN_GAME_TYPE + " = ?",
            new String[]{playerId, "something"},
            null);


}

public void setItem(String playerId){
   this.playerId = playerId;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        doSomething();
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

}
```

Comment: how do you know that the problem is `player_id`?

Comment: Hello, when I debug the playerId has a value in the OnCreateView of the fragment but is null in the MyPagerAdapter.